# Fisher-Yates modern shuffle algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, shuffle

I have implemented the shuffling algorithm of Fisher-Yates in C++, but I've stumbled across the modulo bias.  Is this random number generation by `rand()` correct for Fisher-Yates?

```
srand(time(NULL));
vector<int> elements;
// push numbers from 1 to 9 into the vector
for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i)
{
    elements.push_back(i);
}

// the counter to be used to generate the random number
int currentIndexCounter = elements.size();
for (auto currentIndex = elements.rbegin(); currentIndex != elements.rend() - 1;
     currentIndex++ , --currentIndexCounter)
    {
        int randomIndex = rand() % currentIndexCounter;
        // if its not pointing to the same index      
        if (*currentIndex != elements.at(randomIndex))
        {
            //then swap the elements
            swap(elements.at(randomIndex), *currentIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: rand() is well know for its bad distribution. But you are using it correctly. Note: `rand() % currentIndexCounter` does not give you a perfect distribution unless `currentIndexCounter` is an exact divisor of `RAND_MAX`. You may want to look at C++11 random header and the generators provided inside.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Loki Astari is correct in his comment:

> `rand()` is well know for its bad distribution. But you are using it correctly. Note: `rand() % currentIndexCounter` does not give you a perfect distribution unless `currentIndexCounter` is an exact divisor of `RAND_MAX`. You may want to look at C++11 random header and the generators provided inside.

Since you're using C++11, you should instead utilize the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library.  It includes things such as pseudo-random number generators and random number distributions.

---

Beyond that, I'll just point out some additional things:

- With C++11, you should now be using [`nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr) instead of `NULL`.

  This should be changed in `srand()`:

  ```
  std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
  ```

  However, as mentioned above, you should not be using this with C++11.  But in any situation where you must stay with `rand`, the above would be recommended.
- With C++11, you should also have access to initializer lists.  This will allow you to initialize the vector instead of calling `push_back()` multiple times:

  ```
  std::vector<int> elements { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  ```

  Also note that your `push_back()` was only pushing numbers 1-8 into the vector, despite what your comment said.  You've used `<` instead of `<=` in the loop statement, so the 9 was excluded.
- `currentIndexCounter` should be of type `std::vector<int>::size_type`, which is the return type of `size()` (or you can just use `auto`).  This should've given you compiler warnings as it's a type-mismatch and a possible loss of data.  Make sure your compiler warnings are turned up high.
- `currentIndex` is a misleading name because it's being used with *iterators*, not *indices*.

  Here, `auto` gives `currentIndex` the type [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) from `std::rbegin()`.  You could simply name this something like `iter`.  It's okay for iterator names to be short.
- In the second `for` loop, you just need `elements.rend()`, without the `- 1`.  The iterator will already go through the entire vector and stop at the last reverse element.
- The iterator increment should be prefix instead in order to improve performance a bit by avoiding a copy.  It's best to do this with all nontrivial types such as iterators.
- I've tested this by giving `randomIndex` a value greater than `elements.size()`, causing an exception to be thrown.  Even if `std::rand()` or another RNG is guaranteed to give you an intended value, it may be best to handle this properly.

Here's the final version with my own given changes, which I've also ran [here](http://ideone.com/xVXeeN).  I've also included a concise way of displaying the vector before and after the shuffling.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // seed the RNG
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());

    std::vector<int> elements { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::cout << "Before: ";
    std::copy(elements.cbegin(), elements.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    auto currentIndexCounter = elements.size();

    for (auto iter = elements.rbegin(); iter != elements.rend();
        ++iter, --currentIndexCounter)
    {
        // get int distribution with new range
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, currentIndexCounter);
        const int randomIndex = dis(mt);

        if (*iter != elements.at(randomIndex))
        {
            std::swap(elements.at(randomIndex), *iter);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nAfter: ";
    std::copy(elements.cbegin(), elements.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Before: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> After: 7 9 3 2 4 5 6 1 8
> ```

Comment: is it not possible that ```randomIndex = elements.size()``` on the first iteration of the loop thus resulting in undefined behavior? Unless the prefix decrement on ```currentIndexCounter``` executes on entry of the for loop, possibly?

Comment: @z.karl: That is possible, though that's not one aspect that I caught from the OP's code previously (I only added `auto`).

Answer (score -1):

Here is my take on it with the modern `<random>`:

```cpp
static const void fisher_yates_shuffle(std::deque<card>& cards)
{
  std::random_device                          random                    ;
  std::mt19937                                mersenne_twister(random());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> distribution              ;
  for (auto i = cards.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
  {
    distribution.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t>::param_type(0, i));
    std::swap(cards[i], cards[distribution(mersenne_twister)]);
  }
};
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: I just used this to implement a fisher_yates_shuffle on a Poker program and it works wonderfully, better than other answers.